# Requirement of operator< constness in std::stable_sort

Tags: c++, stl

I'm a bit confused about the difference in requirements of `operator<` `const` qualifier for std::sort and std::stable_sort. Suppose a simple structure:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Custom {
    bool operator<(const Custom& custom) /* const */{
        return true;
    };
};
```

Everything is ok if we try to compile and run this code:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<Custom> values(3);
    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end());
    return 0;
}
```

But this code with `std::stable_sort` failed to compile:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<Custom> values(3);
    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end());
    return 0;
}
```

Here's an error stack trace:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from temp.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of ‘bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_less_iter::operator()(_Value&, _Iterator) const [with _Value = const Custom; _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Custom*, std::vector<Custom> >]’:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:2050:14:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__upper_bound(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with _ForwardIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Custom*, std::vector<Custom> >; _Tp = Custom; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_less_iter]’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:2522:26:   required from ‘void std::__merge_without_buffer(_BidirectionalIterator, _BidirectionalIterator, _BidirectionalIterator, _Distance, _Distance, _Compare) [with _BidirectionalIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Custom*, std::vector<Custom> >; _Distance = long int; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:2782:34:   required from ‘void std::__inplace_stable_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Custom*, std::vector<Custom> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:4863:28:   required from ‘void std::__stable_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Custom*, std::vector<Custom> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:4897:36:   required from ‘void std::stable_sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Custom*, std::vector<Custom> >]’
temp.cpp:15:45:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/predefined_ops.h:71:22: error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const Custom’ and ‘Custom’)
       { return __val < *__it; }
```

So my question is:
Is it just the consequence of technical implementation details or there exists some objective arguments in favor of such behavior?

Comment: None of the code you show ever calls `std::stable_sort`. The error necessarily refers to the code you haven't shown.

Comment: Sometimes, by chance, you get away with not fulfilling all the requirements. The sort algorithms are allowed *but not required* to pass a const value to the comparison. And BTW, always returning `true` is another violation. How do you sort when `a<b` and `b<a` are both true?

Comment: @BoPersson -- I assumed that the `return true;` was to make the **example** simpler; the problem occurs at compile time, not runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **[alg.sorting]/2** `Compare` is a function object type (20.9). The return value of the function call operation applied to an object of type `Compare`, when contextually converted to `bool` (Clause 4), yields `true` if the first argument of the call is less than the second, and `false` otherwise. `Compare comp` is used throughout for algorithms assuming an ordering relation. **It is assumed that `comp` will not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced iterator.**
>
> **[alg.sorting]/3** For all algorithms that take `Compare`, there is a version that uses `operator<` instead. That is, `comp(*i, *j) != false` defaults to `*i < *j != false`.
>
> **[res.on.functions]/1** In certain cases (replacement functions, handler functions, operations on types used to instantiate standard library template components), the C++ standard library depends on components supplied by a C++ program. If these components do not meet their requirements, the Standard places no requirements on the implementation.

Emphasis mine. Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of supplying to a standard library function a component that doesn't meet the function's requirements.

By the way, clang rejects both `std::sort` and `std::stable_sort`.