# Why arguments of comparator function of std::stable_sort() must be set constants?

Tags: c++, sorting, debugging

Hello fellow programmers, I was solving a problem on leetcode that needed sorting in stable order.

Problem link: https://leetcode.com/problems/rearrange-words-in-a-sentence/submissions/

I noticed that arguments of comparator function of std::stable_sort() must be set constants otherwise following compile time error is generated.

Below is the code that generates compile time error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void display(vector<string> &a);
bool compare(string &s1, string &s2);

int main() {
    vector<string> a = {"abc", "defgh", "ijk"};

    // sorting vector<string> in stable order
    // error will be generated
    std::stable_sort(a.begin(), a.end(), compare);
    display(a);
    return 0;
}

// argument strings should be made constants???
bool compare(string &s1, string &s2) {
    return s1.length() < s2.length();
}

void display(vector<string> &a) {
    for(int i=0; i<=a.size()-1; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    return ;
}

// errors generated
/*
    error: binding reference of type ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&’ to ‘const 
    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ discards qualifiers
    177 |  { return bool(_M_comp(*__it, __val)); }

    error: binding reference of type ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&’ to ‘const 
    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ discards qualifiers
    215 |  { return bool(_M_comp(__val, *__it)); }
*/
```

I tried Googling but could not find anything. I searched Stack Overflow and came across a question but could not understand the reason explained there.

Stack Overflow answer link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45905608/13331053

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The function signature (the function type resulting from return type and function parameters) doesn't match what `std::stable_sort()` expects/accepts as custom predicate. It expects a function (or functor) with two references to const type (in your case `const std::string&`) and a return type `bool`. Your `compare()` function simply doesn't fit into this expected signature but it would if you change it to `bool compare(const string &s1, const string &s2)`.

Comment: Okay, I get that. But what could be the reason behind the design decision? Because the `std::sort()` function does not require the arguments of its comparator function to be constants.

Comment: _Because the std::sort() function does not require the arguments of its comparator function to be constants._ Are you sure? AFAIK, `std::sort()` and `std::stable_sort()` have same requirements to the custom predicate.

Comment: [std::sort()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort): _The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the following:

 `bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);`_

Comment: Exactly. It is due to the difference in implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's what the function requires. Quote from cppreference on [`std::stable_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) (emphasis mine):

> The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the following:
>
> ```
> bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
> ```
>
> While the signature does not need to have `const &`, the function must not modify the objects passed to it and must be able to accept all values of type (possibly `const`) `Type1` and `Type2` regardless of value category (**thus, `Type1 &` is not allowed**[, nor is `Type1` unless for `Type1` a move is equivalent to a copy (since C++11)]).

Your function must accept `const` arguments, and non-const reference type doesn't meet this requirement. Thus, your `compare` function should look like this:

```
bool compare(const string &s1, const string &s2);
```

---

GCC accepts the non-const version in `std::sort` all fine: https://godbolt.org/z/S2tL44, despite the fact that [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) has exactly same requirements as `std::stable_sort`. I assume that it is simply not checked anywhere and `std::sort` implementation doesn't rely on constness, but `std::stable_sort` does. Why? That would be a question to the source code (or to standard library mainteiners).

In any case it will be safer and more portable to always use `const&` arguments in such functions to let compiler catch any accidental modifications of objects and make sure it works with every compiler.